# Javascript addEventListener() submit form to wrong php page

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

So I have this form here which should be sent to `create_subscription.php` as the action indicates.

```
<form action="create_subscription.php" method="post" id="stripe-payment-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="card-element">
      Credit or debit card
    </label>
    <div id="card-element"></div>
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
  </div>
  <br>

  <button id='submitmystripepayment' class="btn btn-success">Submit Payment</button>

</form>
```

**This the JavaScript that submits the form**

```
// Handle form submission
var form = document.getElementById('stripe-payment-form');

form.addEventListener('submitmystripepayment', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
            // Inform the user if there was an error
            var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
        } else {
            stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
        }
    });
});

// Send Stripe Token to Server
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('stripe-payment-form');

// Add Stripe Token to hidden input
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

// Submit form
 form.submit();
}
```

However, instead of firing `create_subscription.php`, strangely it goes to `register.php`. Why would it behave like this when the URL Is correct? For your information, and If it is useful, prior to the stripe-payment-form, the user does enter personal details in a totally different form that is being sent to `register.php` with jquery. But I do not even use `addEventListener()`, I use `$(jquery).click()`.

Comment: Check your generated page source. Chances are it is pointing at register.php

Comment: Also check your network requests - maybe you're being redirected to `register.php`

Comment: @Ibu: when you're talking about the page source, what are you referring to?

Comment: @theGleep: How is this even possible?

Comment: @Ibu: After some tests, it seems that it is triggering the previous form which is sign-up-form that is sent to register.php... I'm not truly understanding why would it trigger the previous one and not the one assigned to it?

Comment: By page source I mean, load the page, right click on a blank area and click on page source. This should show you the generated html and you can look if you have the correct url in the form.

Comment: @Ibu: I did what you suggested and in the page source, the form has the correct url. Could the addEventListener conflicts with jquery.click?

Comment: Or you probably have one form nested in the other. The error doesn't seem to be in the code you provided in this question.